# Are threre any Outlook Contacts synchronization components for .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, outlook, components

I am searching for a .NET Winforms component that will give me the ability to easily synchronize the outlook contacts with my application contacts.

Is there any component for this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, if your outlook accounts are managed in an exchange server, is to use the [EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). You can find a sample of code for contact transactions with EWS [here](http://www.stevieg.org/2010/07/using-powershell-to-import-contacts-into-exchange-and-outlook-live/).

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, most of the target users will have Outlook 2010 or an other Outlook version installed. I am searching for something simpler. A .NET component with object mapping so that I could safely synchronize my application contacts with outlook contacts.